# Stuck at "Press F2 or DEL to enter UEFI Bios"

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, bios

I am looking for any help possible.
If there are other subreddits that y'all could recommend for assistance please do.

I was dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 when I encountered an error that required me to purge Ubuntu and reinstall at a later time. After it was uninstalled I tried to remove the option from the boot manager but accidentally selected Ubuntu. My PC immediately rebooted and remained stuck at the ASUS logo with the above message. To top it off the key board and mouse are not recognized so I can't enter the Bios to change settings to boot back to Windows.

I'm assuming that this error is occurring because the PC is trying to boot Ubuntu when it just doesn't exist, but without the keyboard recognition I'm not sure what else to do.

Is this something that I can fix by getting another keyboard to try out?
Or does this need a hard CMOS/Bios reset? (pressing button or removing battery)

I'm not sure what to do/try. Any and all help will be appreciated.
My specs are:

- Intel i5 4690k
- EVGA GTX 1070 FE
- Asus Z97m-Plus